# What is the npm command to build and create package of Apollo Grapphql server application?

Tags: reactjs, npm, graphql, azure-pipelines, apollo-server

What is the npm command to build and create package of Apollo Grapphql server application? I am using nodemon start command to run the application. But I want to create package and publish it in the server. Which npm command we can use for build and packaging?

I am using nodemon start command to run the application. But I want to create package and publish it in the server

Comment: first npm install then  update your package.json to include scripts for building and starting the server after that you can use this npm run build, npm publish ...

Answer (score 0):

In Azure Pipelines, you can use the [**npm task**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/npm-v1?view=azure-pipelines) to execute the related npm commands (such as **`npm install`**,**`npm run build`**, **`npm publish`**, etc..) to build and publish your app.

For more npm commands, see "[**npm CLI**](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/commands/npm)".

---

**EDIT:**

To execute the **`npm run build`** command for your project, **`in the package.json`** file, you need to define the script to run for build process. the script can contain the required command lines for the build process. See below example as reference.

```json
// package.json

{
  "name": "xxxx",
  "version": "xxxx",
  "description": "xxxx",
  "main": "xxxx",
  // Define the scripts for build and test.
  "scripts": {
    "build": "echo \"Building nodejs project...\" && node app.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.33.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "canvas": "^2.11.0"
  }
}
```

In Azure Pipelines, when using the **npm task** to execute the **`npm run build`** command, after selecting '**`custom`**' in the '**Command**' field, you just need to fill '**`run build`**' and arguments you required in the '**Command and arguments**' field. The task will automatically combine '**`npm`**' with '**`run build`**' and the provided arguments to be a complete command line to run. See below example.

```yaml
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm run build'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    workingDir: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/ProjectDir'
    verbose: false
    customCommand: 'run build'
```

[image]

Comment: What should be the build script in package.json? When I run this command npm run build, getting the following error in vs code, because there is no build script in package.json .               npm ERR! Missing script: "build"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

Also in Azure Build pipeline I have added a step 'npm custom'. What should be the value in 'Command and arguments' text box.

Comment: @ManasPal, I have updated my above answer with more information. Check and try it.

Comment: I have added the build step in package.json file and added npm custom task in the pipeline. npm custom tust was running for aout 1 hour and after that failed. Please find the attached log.



1\s\server
2023-11-27T07:48:52.3637768Z ; HOME = C:\Users\VssAdministrator
2023-11-27T07:48:52.3638197Z ; Run `npm config ls -l` to show all defaults.
2023-11-27T07:48:52.3640771Z [command]C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C ""C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd" run build"
2023-11-27T08:48:13.4040670Z ##[error]The operation was canceled.
2023-11-27T08:48:13.4059564Z ##[section]Finishing: npm custom

Comment: @ManasPal, Have you successfully executed the '**`npm run build`**' command for your app on your local develop machine? If the command fails locally, it is not possible to guarantee the command can work in pipeline. You need to ensure it can first work on your local develop machine. Then you can move it into pipeline to run.

Comment: @ManasPal, before running the '**`npm run build`**' command, do not forget to run the '**`npm install`**' command to install the dependencies required by your app.

Comment: Yes npm install step is already there in pipeline.

Comment: @ManasPal, How about building on your local machine?

Comment: I am using npm start to start the server. In package.json
 "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },

Comment: @ManasPal, As suggested previously, ensure the build first can be successful when using the related commands on your local machine. Then try to use the same commands in pipeline to build. When using **`npm`** CLI for your project, ensure your project is written by Node JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. "build": "echo \"Building nodejs project...\" && node app.js", --- this command in package.json will start the server. I want to build and publish the application from azure pipeline.

Comment: I am using this command for build "node app.js". But app.js not exist in the project directory of apollo server. What is the solution?